# Read xml input from a socket server clojure

Tags: java, xml, sockets, clojure

I want to parse xml from a socket. I have tried many examples using clojure.xml/parse but no breakthrough yet. Below is the sample code i started with that only reads text based input:

```
(with-open [sock (Socket. host port)
            reader (io/reader sock)
            response (StringWriter.)]
  (while (.isConnected sock)
    (io/copy reader response)
    (log/info response)))
```

Comment: Can you read anything (text string) from the socket? Or is the problem in parsing and xml string into clojure data structures?

Comment: Yes, I can read text from the socket however with Xml this  is what I' getting: <uxml_err STATUS='12504'/>�

Comment: There must be something wrong in your socket setup. XML is just chars in a string (like `xml-str` in the example). Make sure you can transmit strings like "hello", "<hello/>" "<msg>Hello There</msg>" etc. Once you can read the chars into a string you can then parse them. It is 2 separate problems.

Comment: I'm highly certain that the formatting is the problem, that the server is probably encoding the request as xml. Do you have any insights on how I will be able to receive the full xml input?

Comment: Try 3 tests using the strings above. That should help to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of [doing it using Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive):

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core
        tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.java.io :as io]
    [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as en-html]
    [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

; Discard any xml nodes of Type="A" or Type="B" (plus blank string nodes)
(dotest
  (let [xml-str     "<ROOT>
                      <Items>
                        <Item><Type>A</Type><Note>AA1</Note></Item>
                        <Item><Type>B</Type><Note>BB1</Note></Item>
                        <Item><Type>C</Type><Note>CC1</Note></Item>
                        <Item><Type>A</Type><Note>AA2</Note></Item>
                      </Items>
                    </ROOT>"
        enlive-tree (->> xml-str
                      java.io.StringReader.
                      en-html/html-resource
                      first)]
       (spyx-pretty enlive-tree)))
```

with result:

```
enlive-tree => 
{:tag :ROOT,
 :attrs nil,
 :content
 ("\n                      "
  {:tag :Items,
   :attrs nil,
   :content
   ("\n                        "
    {:tag :Item,
     :attrs nil,
     :content
     ({:tag :Type, :attrs nil, :content ("A")}
      {:tag :Note, :attrs nil, :content ("AA1")})}
    "\n                        "
    {:tag :Item,
     :attrs nil,
     :content
     ({:tag :Type, :attrs nil, :content ("B")}
      {:tag :Note, :attrs nil, :content ("BB1")})}
    "\n                        "
    {:tag :Item,
     :attrs nil,
     :content
     ({:tag :Type, :attrs nil, :content ("C")}
      {:tag :Note, :attrs nil, :content ("CC1")})}
    "\n                        "
    {:tag :Item,
     :attrs nil,
     :content
     ({:tag :Type, :attrs nil, :content ("A")}
      {:tag :Note, :attrs nil, :content ("AA2")})}
    "\n                      ")}
  "\n                    ")}
```

- There is [additional information in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422024/remove-specific-xml-nodes-using-clojure).
- You may also be interested in [The Clojure Cookbook (O'Reilly)](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/49d1ce194bab4be689dae8006cab43427826590c/04_local-io/4-22_read-write-xml.asciidoc)

Comment: Can you share a socket example for the above?